# How to show an Alert window always on top even if a new window is invoked with ShowDialog later on

Tags: wpf, winforms

In my app I have few windows which are displayed using ShowDialog, but we are trying to implement an Alerts window, if Alert window is raised we want it to be always on top even if the ShowDialog window are raised afterwards.

I have set the Alerts window's TopMost and TopLevel properties to 'true', but if a ShowDialog window comes up later, have noticed that even though Alerts window is on top, it is not clickable, while the ShowDialog window is behind, it is clickable and only after closing it the Alerts Window is accessible.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe a second app that deals with alerts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ShowDialog creates a Modal dialog. This means that the dialog MUST be closed before interaction is allowed with the main application (this is enforced by windows).

You need to use modeless dialogs (Use Show instead of ShowDialog to achieve this), or as @rheitzman suggested, make the alerts a different application so the modal dialog rules no longer apply.